# Searching nested object by property name and copying to new object does not result in all objects being copied

Tags: javascript, typescript

[Link to TS Playground.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-GPV6tTodbX656qIIkym0xnqy38c28fnR3V5RAZBxjbJmRPh9Ove3urhC9rdQKhVBk6n02BMzS8cvqWurqei+9r5Ok1i+FUD0TI823PMYYA4aQIA4ddT2DQNjVTCBBGZMB8SvYUfnfD86B-Sh-TdQ8ZyBbCxhA7CQUiCjNCOKU8E3bddxAfd8HQkVRBgViyLwYtS3LVjIUlaFK0fGtEGQH5li4VkgA)

```
const data = {
    "cars": [
        {
            "name": "Audi",
            "color": "blue"
        },
        {
            "name": "Saab",
            "color": "red"
        },
        {
            "year": 2007,
            "owner": "NaN"
        }
    ],

    "boats": {
        "fish": [
            {
                "name": "Salmon",
                "safe": true
            }
        ],
        "sharks": {
            "name": "Great White"
        }
    },

    "trucks": {
        "vans": {
            "bikes": [1, 2, 3]
        }
    }
};

function findProperty(obj: any, property: string): any {
    let result:any = {};

   for(const prop in obj) {
        if(Object.prototype.toString.call(obj[prop]) === "[object Object]" && !obj[prop].hasOwnProperty(property)) 
            return findProperty(obj[prop], property);
        
        for(const i in obj[prop]) {
            if(obj[prop][i].hasOwnProperty(property)) {
                if(result.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
                    result[prop].push(obj[prop][i]);
                } else {
                    Object.assign(result, {
                        [prop]: [obj[prop][i]]
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
};
```

I'm trying to find all arrays with objects that contain the property `name` no matter how nested the initial data object is; and for some reason the final result only contains 1 result instead of all of them.

When I debug at line 45 with

```
console.log(obj[prop][i])
```

I can see that it finds all objects; all 3 of them, yet only one of them is present in the final result.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Why is `cars` an array, but boats and trucks are objects?

Comment: You keep making a new object

Comment: @Taplar They are intended to be like that. Basically, if the value is an array, it contains objects I want to extract. However, it can also be nested, meaning that this array can be further down inside the object, which is being demonstrated by having `boats` and `trucks` being objects.

Comment: @epascarello Can't believe I missed that. Thank you for pointing that out, works like intended now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You keep making a new result object so you probably want to create it once and pass it along

```
function findProperty(obj: any, property: string, result: any = {}): any {

   for(const prop in obj) {
        if(Object.prototype.toString.call(obj[prop]) === "[object Object]" && !obj[prop].hasOwnProperty(property)) 
            return findProperty(obj[prop], property, result);
        
        for(const i in obj[prop]) {
            if(obj[prop][i].hasOwnProperty(property)) {
                console.log(obj[prop][i]);
                
                if(result.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
                    result[prop].push(obj[prop][i]);
                } else {
                    Object.assign(result, {
                        [prop]: [obj[prop][i]]
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }

    console.log("result:", result);
    return result;
};
```

Comment: Yes, you are completely right about that. Will accept when it lets me.